# Can I use RavenDB during an Export? What happens to documents added?

Tags: migration, export, ravendb

If I've started a large export of data using smuggler, can I continue to use RavenDB while the export is happening?

If a document gets added during the export, will it get exported?

The documentation states you can continue to use RavenDB while importing.  See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/1.0/csharp/server/administration/export-import.  I cannot find anything about exporting though.

And I will be exporting for RavenDB server V1 (build 888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RavenDB during the export.
In current versions of RavenDB, the export will continue to run on a snapshot of the data. But will query the database again when it is done to get documents that were added during the export.

In build 888, however, you get the documents that were in the database when the export started, not the ones added during the export.